# Cohomology of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{F}_2)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

I’m wondering what is known about the cohomology of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z}_2)$, the general linear group of $3\times3$ matrices over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. There are results in Chapter I of Knudson’s “[Homology of Linear Groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8338-2)” as well as Chapter VII of Adem and Milgram’s “[Cohomology of Finite Groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-06280-7)” that consider the cohomology of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, but not this specific case.

Update: It seems that Adem and Milgram does the trick once we identify $\operatorname{GL}(3,2) =\operatorname{SL}(3,2)$. The relevant lemma says that
$$H^*(\operatorname{SL}(3,2)) \oplus H^*(D_8) \cong H^*(S_4)\oplus H^*(S_4). $$

Comment: Is it possible you meant [Knudson - Homology of linear groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-8338-2)?  [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/publications-search?query=au%3AKnudson+title%3Ahomology+pt%3Abook&page=1&size=20&sort=newest&facets=) doesn't know Kudson - Homology of finite groups.

Comment: Yes, I meant Knudson. Thank you for catching that typo.

Comment: Page 178 contains material about symmetric groups. Maybe you mean page 278?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It appears that I have an earlier copy of the book. For the version linked in my question, it should be somewhere in Chapter V, G-Complexes and Equivariant Cohomology.

Comment: I see, thanks. In the 2004 edition it is on page 173.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mention in your update, you have a general answer, but if you want a concrete answer for the low-dimensional integral cohomology of $G = \operatorname{GL}(3,2)$ (or any other finite group!), you can use [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/index.html), specifically the `hap` package. The following code computes $H^i(G, \mathbf{Z})$  for $i \leq 10$:

```
LoadPackage("hap"); 
G = GL(3,2); 
List([1..10], x->GroupCohomology(G, x));
```

This will output:

```
[ [  ], [  ], [ 2 ], [ 4, 3 ], [  ], [ 2, 2, 7 ], [ 2 ], [ 4, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2 ] ]
```

which is a list of the abelian invariants of the cohomology groups $H^i(G, \mathbf{Z})$ for $1 \leq i \leq 10$, i.e. the first ten integral cohomology groups are $1, 1, C_2, C_4 \times C_3, 1, C_2 \times C_2 \times C_7, C_2, C_4 \times C_3, C_2 \times C_2$ and $C_2 \times C_2$ (for readability I here use $C_n = \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$).

If you want to compute the mod $p$ cohomology, and don't feel like using the above with the universal coefficient theorem by hand, you can compute this just as easily by using `GroupCohomology(G, x, p)`. When $p=2$, the sequence of exponents of the first ten cohomology groups (together with $H^0(G, \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})$) is
$$
1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3 
$$
e.g., $H^3(G, \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}) \cong (\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^2$. This sequence (of course) agrees with the generating function in @DaveBenson's answer, which expands as:
$$
\frac{1+t^3}{(1-t^2)(1-t^3)} = 1 + \quad + t^2 + 2 t^3 + t^4 + 2 t^5 + 3 t^6 + 2 t^7 + 3 t^8 + 4 t^9 + 3 t^{10} + ...
$$

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Answer (score 11):

For the mod $2$ cohomology, see Section 11 of Benson and Carlson, “[Diagrammatic methods for modular representations and cohomology](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927878708823414)” Comm in Alg 15 (1987), 53-121 for the ring structure. If you want to know about the $A_\infty$ structure, and much more information besides, see [Benson - Classifying spaces of finite groups of tame representation type](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.07913). At odd primes, the group has cyclic Sylow subgroup, so the cohomology is easy.

In the mod 2 cohomology, as given in the first reference above, there's a generator in degree 2, two generators in degree 3, and one relation, saying that the product of the two degree 3 generators is equal to zero. This gives a generating function for the dimensions of $\frac{1+t^3}{(1-t^2)(1-t^3)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!

Comment: Probably the easiest way to compute the Steenrod action is to restrict to the Sylow $2$-subgroup, which is dihedral of order $8$. Letting $H^*(G,\mathbb{F}_2)=\mathbb{F}_2[x,y,z]/(xy)$ with $|x|=|y|=3$ and $|z|=2$, the answers are: $Sq^1(z)=x+y$, $Sq^2(z)=z^2$, $Sq^1(x)=Sq^1(y)=0$, $Sq^2(x)=xz$, $Sq^2(y)=yz$. Ah! your question seems to have disappeared while I was typing an answer.

Comment: Thanks @DaveBenson! Not sure why my edited question didn't repost, but for those wondering, I asked about the Steenrod squares of $SL(3,2)$.